# linking created users to database in firebase web app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How do I link the authenticated users to my firebase database in my Angular JS web app?

I understand that I would have to create a node in my database tree for each user. I have created a node in my database tree called "users" for this. What I do not understand is how to get each user to occupy a sub-node in my "users" node in my database such that once logged in, all the data each user saves is saved under their respective sub-nodes.

This is my code at the moment:

```
         $scope.saveTeam = function(user){
$scope.history = [];

 var uid = user.uid;

var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/week"); 


 ref2.set($scope.history);

  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which ever method you are using to signup users has a promise returned .

For example consider signing up users with email and password:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
    (user) =>{
        let usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
         //child is created under users node with a user's user id as child name
        usersRef.child(user.uid).set({
            email: user.email,
            userName: username,
            displayPicUrl: 'any url.'
          });
    }, error => {
        //handle errors here
    }
);
```

So you can do the process of writing a new user to database in ths promise's fullfilled part as shown above.
This ensures that a user node is created only if user sign up was successful

**so in your code add like this**

```
$scope.signUp = function (){
   var username = $scope.user.email;
   var password = $scope.user.password;
   if(username && password){
         var auth = $firebaseAuth();
             auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(function(user){
                 console.log("User Successfully Created");
                let usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
                 //child is created under users node with a user's user id as child name
                usersRef.child(user.uid).set({
                    email: user.email,
                    userName: username,
                    displayPicUrl: 'any url.'
                  });

                 $location.path('/home');
             }).catch(function(error){
                $scope.errMsg = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
             });
 }
 };
```

You are not passing `user` parameter in `then()`

Comment: it did not seem to work. I will edit the answer to  show the code i have for registration. There is a registration form in the scope.

Comment: @user7814783 It seems the OP submitted an edit of your answer to the review queue and changed your whole code twice. Check the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43952027/timeline) of your answer to see the edits. I rejected the second one.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am using stack overfliw on andoud tablet. So cant view your edits so post it in your quesrion the code you have tried

Comment: @user7814783 it directs the user to the home view.

Comment: @DejiJames okay, then what is your problem?

Comment: @user7814783 my problem is how to get the user's details entered into the registration form to also be entered into the database under the "users" node.

Comment: @user7814783 it worked! Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @user7814783 quick question. How would I reference a specific user child node since the parent node will be the Useruid? Using firebase.database().ref().child('users').child('uid').child('email') doesnt work.

Comment: @DejiJames you can do like this firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/email") , where uid is user's uid which you get by user.uid

Comment: @user7814783 I edited my question to show my code at the moment. It didn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @DejiJames firebase's set method takes in object as its parameter not an array $scope.history is an array but set method takes an object { }. So it should be ref.set({ some object }). There are no arrays in firebase databases

Comment: @DejiJames and yeah you are asking these many questions , consider giving upvotes to the answer or comment if it helped you

Comment: Just did thanks. Apparently it doesn't display on the answer page but the vote is recorded.