# Creating user node on firebase signup

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup my app so that when a user signs up they are added to a 'users' node in the database. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951888/linking-created-users-to-database-in-firebase-web-app) example for how to do it but my program isn't recognizing the userId when it creates the users so it doesn't create the child node in the database. Here is my code for the signup:

```
signup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.password === this.state.verifyPass){
        fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user) => {
            console.log('user created');
            let usersRef = fire.database().ref('users');
            console.log(user.uid);
            usersRef.child(user.uid).set({
                email: this.state.email,
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message})
            this.handleSnackbar();
        });
    }else{
        alert("Passwords do not match");
    }
}
```

The problem happens at the second console.log which returns "*undefined*" to the console. The users are being created and added to the auth of the firebase but I can't figure out adding them to the database.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: to get to the user id I needed to use `user.user.uid` not `user.uid`